# spring transaction management with jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I am running a java project using jdbctemplate in which update of 2000 records is happening with batch size of 500 records.

Since, i am using single update query would there improvement in application if i would use spring transaction management ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it would help in the performance as code is going to hit the database only once

even I would suggest to use

```
@Override
public <S extends Classname> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> arg0);
```

Which save the entities present in list directly to database without using either jdbcTemplate or transaction management

Comment: you mean all 2000 records would hit database only once even if i am executing jdbcTemplate.update() in batch size of 500 ? Also, can you elaborate more on your suggestion ?

Comment: @ankitjava the main thing about my suggestion is to use the **PagingAndSortingRepository** interface

Comment: `public interface ClassRepository extends
  PagingAndSortingRepository<ClassEntity, String> {

 @Override
 public <S extends ClassName> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> arg0);

}`

Answer (score 0):

this is decided by your requirement. if 2000 records must constants,so you have to use transaction management,if not , you can deal one record every time.

Comment: i don't know if you understood my question

Answer (score 0):

It can definitely help you. You can make the 500 record batch calls one by one in a Java method annotated with @Transactional annotation. That way, spring will roll back the whole operation in the event that any of the update fails.

P.S: I haven't specified any XML configurations where you have to specify your transaction manager. You can add a suitable one meeting your needs.